# Time Attendance Report using MySql in Laravel

Tags: mysql

Good Day!

I'm would like to generate a report that would display like the one in the attached photo. [Click this example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PopAd.jpg)

I would like to separate the datetime into Time In AM (7:00AM), Time Out AM (12:00AM), Time In PM(12:30AM), Time Out PM((5:00PM) in the query

So far this is what I get, a static date only, I don't know how to make it dynamic by using the timerange only [Click the example photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/corXb.jpg). Hope you can help. Thank you.

```
select datetime,id,
(CASE WHEN datetime > '19/04/2021 6:30' AND datetime < '19/04/2021 8:30' THEN datetime ELSE NULL END) as TimeInAM,
(CASE WHEN datetime > '19/04/2021 11:30' AND datetime < '19/04/2021 12:30' THEN datetime ELSE NULL END) as TimeOutAM,
(CASE WHEN datetime > '19/04/2021 12:30' AND datetime < '19/04/2021 13:30'THEN datetime ELSE NULL END) as TimeInPM,
(CASE WHEN datetime > '19/04/2021 16:30' AND datetime < '19/04/2021 21:30'THEN datetime ELSE NULL END) as TimeOutPM
from time_attendances WHERE id = 1345
```

Comment: You really should not use sql to format your output, use a proper reporting software for this purpose!

Comment: In terms of the output, I will use Laravel. I don't know if it is the right application to use. I'm thinking also of MS Access but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to not using reserved `MySQL` words such as `datetime`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Are you trying something like this:

```
SELECT d,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '06:30:00 AM' and '08:30:00 AM' ,  d, 'Null' )  as TimeInAM ,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '11:30:00 AM' and '12:29:59 AM' ,  d, 'Null' )  as TimeOutAM ,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '12:30:00 AM' and '01:30:00 PM' ,  d, 'Null' )  as TimeInPM ,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '04:30:00 PM' and '09:30:00 AM' ,  d, 'Null' )  as TimeOutPM 
from test ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/62

`DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%r')` return date in `07:01:00 AM`,`09:30:00 PM`  format.

Check based on your values and let me now.

Edit:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/67

```
SELECT d,dayname(d) as week_day,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '06:30:00 AM' and '08:30:00 AM' ,  DATE_FORMAT(d,"%h:%i %p"), 'Null' )  as TimeInAM ,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '11:30:00 AM' and '12:29:59 AM' ,  DATE_FORMAT(d,"%h:%i %p"), 'Null' )  as TimeOutAM ,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '12:30:00 AM' and '01:30:00 PM' ,  DATE_FORMAT(d,"%h:%i %p"), 'Null' )  as TimeInPM ,
if( DATE_FORMAT(d,'%r') between '04:30:00 PM' and '09:30:00 PM' ,  DATE_FORMAT(d,"%h:%i %p"), 'Null' )  as TimeOutPM 
from test   order by d desc ;
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it also possible to output it like this? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tfOU4mEHY8J_HjV4lLmf6AFgENgypc-5/view?usp=sharing To join them if they have the same date?

Comment: @RomneelBacon check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/66